# CentOS - Yum doesn't update anymore?

Tags: linux, terminal, centos, yum

I've been trying to use yum now, but for some reason, not even the search work anymore. I even tried putting packages I already downloaded in the search criteria and is the same.

```
[root@AMDFX03 Downloads]# yum search glibc
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/metalink                                            |  22 kB     00:00     
 * base: centos.secrel.com.br
 * epel: archive.linux.duke.edu
 * extras: centos.secrel.com.br
 * rpmforge: apt.sw.be
 * updates: centos.secrel.com.br
adobe-linux-x86_64/primary                               | 1.2 kB     00:00     
http://linuxdownload.adobe.com/linux/x86_64/repodata/primary.xml.gz:
[Errno -1] Metadata file does not match checksum
Trying other mirror.
Error: failure: repodata/primary.xml.gz from adobe-linux-x86_64:
[Errno 256] No more  mirrors to try.
```

This error always appear no matter what I do.
Please, can you tell me how to fix this, or at least how to reset yum's configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, thanks to SnakeDoc for the help, I was feeling hopeless with this error.
Second, I found in a forum that by adding http_caching=none to the yum.conf file in /etc/, I managed to fix the problem.

Seems that with "yum clean all" was cleaning, but was retrieving the corrupted metadata from the cache. With this, it'll be okay.

Comment: i encountered the same problem with Fedora 18, i just temporarily disabled the adobe repository (`yum --disablerepo adobe*` or edit it's repository file in `/etc/yum.repo.d`), and then everything will be working again.

Answer (score 0):

what centos are you on? 4.9 was EOL i think a bit ago and caused a similar issue to one of our servers.

```
sudo uname -a
sudo cat /etc/redhat-release
```

Paste the output of both cmds please.

it sounds like the GPG keys are out of date or invalid.

```
rpm --import http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5
```

or

```
rpm --import http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
```

You should also try:

```
sudo yum clean metadata
sudo yum clean all
```

Comment: I'm on CentOS 6.3, by the way.

Comment: sudo yum clean all might be the trick... i think either your keys are busted or yum database/cache is busted

Comment: I tried from the url and also from a file in which I save the contents of the key for CentOS 6. It says: "curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
error: http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6: import read failed(2)."

Comment: OK, i managed to download the key, but it's the same result. The same error appears. I also put the "clean all" command from yum. u__u

Comment: sudo yum clean metadata

Comment: I found the answer. I added http_caching=none to the yum.conf file. Seems the cache was kind of tampered and that's why was reloading corrupted metadata everytime.

Comment: @Xanathos, +1 Please post the answer you found and accept it as the answer. Thanks.